# Port password protection for a container

Tags: docker, port, password-protection

I am using Docker and would like to run a container, that uses a given public port. This port should be protected, users should be authenticated with one given username/password. Does Docker have some features for this purpose?

Comment: Maybe you can add port knocking in your container? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking

Comment: Have you considered securing the port using SSL and client certificates? Better and more standard approach to securing docker. See: https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/

Answer (score 0):

You could run another container (like NGiNX or Apache one) which would be in charge of:

- authentication
- reverse-proxy to your first container port

That way, the first container port (`EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile) does not have to be mapped to the host: it is directly accessed by the second container, run with a [`--link` option](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links)

Comment: Is there any paired containers available for testing? I would like to try it, because this method is a bit unclear for me.

Comment: @mum007 I do the authentication in my apache-ldap containers: https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/f9890cb6e1ee14842b8be2dd66a754550db793a9/apache/env.conf#L109-L119, based on a link to the ldap container (https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/f9890cb6e1ee14842b8be2dd66a754550db793a9/apache/run#L61-L65) which I run first: https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/f9890cb6e1ee14842b8be2dd66a754550db793a9/apache/run#L61-L65